# Open Graph (OG) tags not being read but are definitely there

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have been using the debugger links but I'm not getting any actual errors, just some warnings. And the meta tags are there, when I browse to the page and when I look at what the FB scraper is bringing back.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm ready to bash my head into a wall.

site url: https://mobileqa.1stdibs.com/paper/new-and-custom-catalog-spring-2018/96023/532243/

share debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmobileqa.1stdibs.com%2Fpaper%2Fnew-and-custom-catalog-spring-2018%2F96023%2F532243%2F

object debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `property="og:image"` not `type="og:image"` and the same for all the others. As explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I could have sworn "type" worked in the past, perhaps both were accepted and aren't anymore? I'm still having image trouble but I will investigate separately. Thank you again!!!